# import & export icons.js component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, export, icons

I created an `icons.js` file that imports all icons from the `react-icons` package. How can export this file so that all other components can use it?

Here is my `icons.js` file:

> ```
> import {BiStore} from 'react-icons/bi';
> import {RiBarChartBoxLine} from 'react-icons/ri';
> import {RiCalendarTodoLine} from 'react-icons/ri';
> import {RiPaintBrushLine} from 'react-icons/ri';
> import {RiDatabase2Line} from 'react-icons/ri';
> ...
> LIST GOES ON
> ...
> ```

I am trying to use the `icons.js` file in my other components, but I don't know how to import & export this file.

Comment: Do you use ALL of these icons in "_all other component._"? Why do you want to do this? To cut down on the amount of code in each module? The solution is to put each imported name into an object that you then export from your icons.js file - if you really should is a different topic I guess.

Comment: some icons are used very much in several components for example chevron icons . that I to avoid repetition , create this file . Is there a standard and better way to do this? 
 What is the strategy of importing and exporting the icons in the react projects?

Comment: At the end of the `icons.js` file, you can export them: `export { iconName, iconName2, ... }` but you'll still have to import the icon(s) from the `icons.js` file. So, unless you're creating pre-made components with the icons like `export const navLinks = { title: Skype, icon: <BsSkype />, ... }` then I'd just import them individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in your icons.js:

```
export {BiStore} from 'react-icons/bi';
export {RiBarChartBoxLine as ChartLine} from 'react-icons/ri';
```

Answer (score 0):

your imports are correct. Then, to use those icons, you could use them like a component or tag. Here's the syntax:

```
import {BiStore} from 'react-icons/bi';
const About = () => {
return (
<div>
<h1>This is sample About page or component</h1>
<BiStore />
</div>
);
}
export default About
```

The icons also have properties like color, size, etc. Another, you could also put classes in it like styling a div. Like this:

react-icons properties

```
<BiStore size={20}/>
```

react-icons styling

```
<BiStore className="hover:scale-150 duration-500 hover:text-accent" size={20}/>
```

Note: the styling depends on what styling you are using, in this example I used tailwindcss.